# CLLocationManager and distanceFilter?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, cllocationmanager, cllocation

i want to change the `distanceFilter` value on the basis of current speed. I try to change `distanceFilter` value after calling `startUpdatinglocation` on the basis of current speed, but it doesn't make any difference. Its giving location updates for every 10 meters because in starting i set `distanceFilter` value to 10. What i think i need to call `stopUpdatingLocation` and then `startUpdatingLocation` to make changes is `distanceFilter` value. But my concern is if i call `stopUpdatingLocation` and `startUpdatingLocation` frequently then will it drain more battery ? or in simple words if i try to start/stop GPS receiver more frequently then will it consume more power or not ?

Answer (score 0):

yes it uses power to find satellites and lock on to them. I use a singleton for my location manager and it has a cllocation manager property I have tried to change to call

```
 ` [location.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:100.0f];
    [location.locationManager setDistanceFilter:100.0f];`
```

and Im not getting and errors so you can just change it on the fly